# Tree list with angular material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tree, angular-material, angularjs-ng-include

Good day, I'm trying to create tree list from list of items with parent and childs id, that I recursive find with angular material based on following link
http://codepen.io/dunmaksim/pen/GJLogo/, but there is something wrong in my code. Child level depends on item.expanded.

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="dirtyDataFromServer.html">
    <md-list-item flex>
        <md-checkbox aria-label="item" ng-model='item.checked' md-indeterminate="isIndeterminate(item, $event)" ng-click="toggleChildrenChekboxes(item, $event)"></md-checkbox>
        <label>{{ item.id }}. {{ item.name }}</label>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-icon style="z-index:100" class="material-icons">
            <i ng-click="toggleItems(item, $event)" class="material-icons">{{item.expanded ? 'expand_less' : 'expand_more' }}</i>
        </md-icon>
    </md-list-item>
    <md-list flex ng-show="item.expanded">
        <div class="list-left-margin" ng-repeat="item in item.subObjs" ng-include="'dirtyDataFromServer.html'"></div>
    </md-list>
</script>
```

So, whats happens here

```
1.item 1
2.item 2
      3.item 3
      4.item 4
           6.item 6
           7.item 7
5.item 5
```

but when I expand, for example item 4:

```
1.item 1
2.item 2
      3.item 3
      4.item 4
           6.item 6
           7.item 7
      6.item 6
      7.item 7
5.item 5
```

It create dubble at same level, items are simmilar, but in DOM they are different.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in data, problem solved.